# select top records from multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which list loggin users each time they login. the table is like this

```
id  |  user | cmd   | ts
1   |  john | login | 2014-01-19 18:26:01
2   |  mark | login | 2014-01-19 18:36:00
3   |  john | login | 2014-01-19 18:40:13
4   |  dave | login | 2014-01-19 18:41:58
5   |  john | login | 2014-01-19 18:50:59
6   |  mark | login | 2014-01-19 19:03:23
7   |  dave | login | 2014-01-19 19:15:13
8   |  mark | login | 2014-01-19 19:26:58
```

i need to select only the latest login from this table, so the output i expect is

```
id  |  user | cmd   | ts
5   |  john | login | 2014-01-19 18:50:59
7   |  dave | login | 2014-01-19 19:26:58
8   |  mark | login | 2014-01-19 19:15:13
```

this is what i tried

```
SELECT * FROM `logins` group by user having count(*) <= 1 order by ts
```

i got zero rows

Comment: What I'm missing here is what are you trying to achieve by `having count(*) <=1` ? And how does your query will give you the expected output of `id, user, cmd, ts` while you asking for `user, ts, count(*)` ?

Comment: please paste your create, insert table query here so we can taste easily

Comment: you can use LIMIT to limit the number of records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,user,cmd,MAX(ts) ts FROM `logins`
group by user
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order is missing a direction. Try adding either ASC or DESC. In your case it would be DESC

`order by ts DESC`

Comment: yea, but thats not the bug, i still get zero rows with the desc

Comment: remove the group by statement `group by user having count(*) <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user,ts,count(*) FROM `logins`  LIMIT 3  group by user order by ts DESC
```